# Comparar archivos de un directorio y mostrar los no repetidos python

Tags: python, lista, comparaciones

Necesito comparar los archivos de un directorio y obtener los que no esten repetidos pero casi tienen un nombre identico ejemplo:

```
prueba.txt
prueba_expand.txt

prueba2.txt
prueba2_expand.txt

prueba3.txt
prueba3_expand.txt

prueba4.txt
prueba5.txt
```

en concreto solo quiero prueba 4 y 5

uso este codigo parar hace la filtracion apenas y solo me falta comparar por ciertos caracteres y buscar los que no son repetidos

```
def filtrarCoincidencias(ruta,extension):
    files=[ x for x in os.listdir(ruta) if x.endswith(extension)]
    coincidencias=[]
    print files
    for i,f1 in enumerate(files):
        for j,f2 in enumerate(files):
            if(j>i):
                if(filecmp.cmp(ruta+f1,ruta+f2)):
                    coincidencias.append((f1,f2))
    return coincidencias


for tupla in filtrarCoincidencias("ruta del directorio",".ass"):
    print(tupla)
```

Comment: Tienes que definir "identico". Una manera es proporcionar una función que mide la similitud entre dos palabras. ¿Puedes publicar el código que usas para medir la similitud?

Answer (score 0):

El problema central es definir y calcular similitud. Para esto usara la función `difflib.ndiff`. Esta función es un generador que produce las diferencias entre dos palabras, como se muestra en el ejemplo:

```
[x for x in difflib.ndiff("palabra1", "palabra2")]
```

produce

```
['  p', '  a', '  l', '  a', '  b', '  r', '  a', '- 1', '+ 2']
```

Lo que nos importa son los elementos que empiezan con "-" y "+", los que señalan caracteres que deben ser insertados o eliminados de la primera palabra para hacerla igual a la segunda palabra.

Con esto, mi *arbitraria* definición de *parecido* es:

> dos palabras son parecidas si el total de modificaciones ("-" y "+")
> es menor que un limite (por ejemplo, 4).

Mi función de comparación será

```
import difflib

def diferencias(palabra1, palabra2, max):
    """ Compara dos palabras

    @param palabra1: La primera palabra
    @param palabra2: La segunda palabra.
    @param max: Maximo numero de discrepancias aceptables
    @return: True si las dos palabras tienen a lo más max diferencias.
    """
    total_neg = 0
    total_pos = 0
    for dif in difflib.ndiff(palabra1, palabra2):
        if dif[0] == "-":
            total_neg += 1
        elif dif[0] == "+":
            total_pos += 1

    print(palabra1, palabra2, total_neg, total_pos)

    return (total_neg + total_pos) <= max
```

Nota: He dejado separado la contabilidad de adiciones y eliminaciones para facilitar la aplicacion de otros criterios de similitud.

Tengo un directorio con este contenido:

```
20180927_182610.jpg  20190220_130357.jpg  DSCN1930.jpg  DSCN1937.jpg
20180927_182628.jpg  20190220_130403.jpg  DSCN1931.MOV  DSCN1938.jpg
20181215_161317.jpg  20190220_130405.jpg  DSCN1932.jpg  DSCN1939.jpg
20181215_161319.jpg  20190330_161846.jpg  DSCN1933.jpg  out
20181215_161324.jpg  20190330_161850.jpg  DSCN1934.jpg
20181215_161326.jpg  20190330_161903.jpg  DSCN1935.jpg
20190220_130354.jpg  20190907_224410.jpg  DSCN1936.jpg
```

Modifique ligeramente tu código para probarlo:

```
def filtrarCoincidencias(ruta,extension):
    files=[x for x in os.listdir(ruta) if x.endswith(extension)]
    coincidencias=[]
    for i, f1 in enumerate(files):
        for j, f2 in enumerate(files):
            if(j > i):
                if diferencias(f1, f2, 4):
                    coincidencias.append((f1,f2))
                else:
                    print("rechazada")
    return coincidencias


for tupla in filtrarCoincidencias("/home/candid/inter3",".jpg"):
     print(tupla)
```

Lo que produce el resultado a continuación:

Nota: he dejado varios prints para poder seguir y chequear la operación. Las primeras lineas reflejan el calculo en la función `diferencias`.

```
20181215_161317.jpg 20180927_182628.jpg 7 7
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg DSCN1933.jpg 13 6
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg 20181215_161326.jpg 2 2
20181215_161317.jpg 20190220_130403.jpg 8 8
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg 20190220_130405.jpg 8 8
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg 20190330_161850.jpg 8 8
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg DSCN1936.jpg 13 6
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg 20190907_224410.jpg 11 11
rechazada
20181215_161317.jpg 20181215_161319.jpg 1 1
20181215_161317.jpg DSCN1938.jpg 13 6
rechazada
... blah, blah ....
('20181215_161317.jpg', '20181215_161326.jpg')
('20181215_161317.jpg', '20181215_161319.jpg')
('20181215_161317.jpg', '20181215_161324.jpg')
('20180927_182628.jpg', '20180927_182610.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1936.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1938.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1939.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1932.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1934.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1930.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1933.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('20181215_161326.jpg', '20181215_161319.jpg')
('20181215_161326.jpg', '20181215_161324.jpg')
('20190220_130403.jpg', '20190220_130405.jpg')
('20190220_130403.jpg', '20190220_130354.jpg')
('20190220_130403.jpg', '20190220_130357.jpg')
('20190220_130405.jpg', '20190220_130354.jpg')
('20190220_130405.jpg', '20190220_130357.jpg')
('20190330_161850.jpg', '20190330_161846.jpg')
('20190330_161850.jpg', '20190330_161903.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1938.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1939.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1932.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1934.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1930.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1936.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('20181215_161319.jpg', '20181215_161324.jpg')
('DSCN1938.jpg', 'DSCN1939.jpg')
('DSCN1938.jpg', 'DSCN1932.jpg')
('DSCN1938.jpg', 'DSCN1934.jpg')
('DSCN1938.jpg', 'DSCN1930.jpg')
('DSCN1938.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1938.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('20190220_130354.jpg', '20190220_130357.jpg')
('DSCN1939.jpg', 'DSCN1932.jpg')
('DSCN1939.jpg', 'DSCN1934.jpg')
('DSCN1939.jpg', 'DSCN1930.jpg')
('DSCN1939.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1939.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('DSCN1932.jpg', 'DSCN1934.jpg')
('DSCN1932.jpg', 'DSCN1930.jpg')
('DSCN1932.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1932.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('DSCN1934.jpg', 'DSCN1930.jpg')
('DSCN1934.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1934.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('DSCN1930.jpg', 'DSCN1935.jpg')
('DSCN1930.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
('DSCN1935.jpg', 'DSCN1937.jpg')
```

**Observaciones:**

filecmp.cmp no compara los nombres de archivos.

Hay una versión más pitonica de la función de comparación, que sería esta:

```
def diferencia2(palabra1, palabra2, max):
    return len([dif for dif in difflib.ndiff(palabra1, palabra2) if dif[0] != ' ']) <= max
```

Es más compacta, pero poco adaptable si deseas cambiar el criterio de similitud.